# How do you split a string into lines with a regular expression in Python?

Tags: python, regex, string

I have a logfile with 4 lines, for example:

```
12/12/2015 18:00:00 Computer:PC_1 (Rel:7.8.x)                                      
ERROR message: 1245456487                                                         
The wifi was not available                                                        
The user needs to validate
```

Now I want to split the second line from the first line with a regular expression in Python to get:

```
line1 == '12/12/2015 18:00:00 Computer:PC_1 (Rel:7.8.x)'          
line2 == '2 ERROR message: 1245456487'
```

Comment: You haven't specified any kind of pattern other than "it's on a different line," which of course doesn't need a regex.

Comment: Is there any way how you can split lines? So far I have this: l = s.split (" "). I'm new to Python and I just started scripting.

Comment: you can try, `s.splitlines()`

Answer (score 1):

You can simply split your logfile into a list of lines likes this:

```
with open('mylogfile.txt') as f:
    lines = list(f)
```

`lines[0]` would be the first line, `lines[1]` the second line, and so on.

Splitting an instance of `str` into lines can be done like this:

```
>>> s="""12/12/2015 18:00:00 Computer:PC_1 (Rel:7.8.x) 
... ERROR message: 1245456487 
... The wifi was not available
... The user needs to validate"""
>>> lines = s.splitlines()
>>> lines[0]
'12/12/2015 18:00:00 Computer:PC_1 (Rel:7.8.x)'
>>> lines[1]
'ERROR message: 1245456487'
```

You don't need a regular expression for this task in either case.

Comment: What if the newline character isn't `'\n'`? You should be using `os.linesep` instead

Comment: @MukundMK If it is read as text file then the newline character *is* `'\n'` regardless what the OS uses as byte sequence on disk.